# Set font (typeface) in rmarkdown YAML for pdf output

Tags: pdf, fonts, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to set the font for a pdf document created in rMarkdown

```
---
title: "Intro"
date: "10/07/2020"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Arial
---
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error

```
tlmgr.pl: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `unicode-math.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update to texlive2020? Also if you would install a complete distribution, you won't have any problems with missing packages anymore

Comment: Thanks: Yes I've updated Tinytex and that's fixed it. I've not had to do that before. What do you mean by a complete ditribution?

Comment: tinytex installs just a part of texlive. If you install texlive yourself you can select the "full scheme" which will install most latex packages that exist and you'll never again have problems about missing packages. Takes more disk space but safes a lot of trouble.